# external pop email relay

Tags: linux, email, pop3

I want to offer to my customer this possibility :

- get her pop3 emails from external pop3 server
- forward the news emails to the new external pop3 server

I have find lot of tools for sync imap accounts, or sync pop to imap, but i just want get pop and send to another email adress !

I search a answer for linux ( if i can make a simple daemon for make it's it's good ).

Thanks a lot for your help.

---

edit for more detail :

For simplify my question, in my use case, it's just want to connect as client via pop protocol ( like a mail app ).
And i check news emails, and forward to other email adress.
I search about an app or code for create this on linux.

In this situation have no access to mailbox dirs, or server configuration ( in this case i have already the answer by create a qmail hook )

Maybe, it's not the good website ? my question must be post on the stackoverflow part ?

Comment: I think that you could do it with a local linux MUA, like mutt, or Pine with a .forward file. You are looking to do the last example I mentioned, have a look at `bouncing mail in Mutt` or Pine. You can also script these things, but be careful if the mail account is not hosted by you, you will need to be careful to keep the login info secure.

Comment: Thanks NickW. Can you post this as answer, i want to select it as good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can forward people's mail to other servers in any number of ways, when your MTA receives it, when your LDA places it into the Maildir/Mailbox, or when scripts are run by the client (mail filters).

Since you indicate you want to do it at the MUA level, I'd suggest Mutt, or Pine with a .forward file. Have a look at `bouncing mail in Mutt` or Pine. You can also script these things, but be careful if the mail account you are forwarding for is not hosted by you, you will need to be vigilant to keep the login info secure.

Comment: Your answer is really good, but i have add more details, because my question seems confused.